# How to use Regular expression in JavaScript to replace a set of characters with an empty string?

Tags: javascript

Can anybody help me writing a regular expression to replace these characters with a empty string. Character list is given below.

```
public static char[] delimiters = { ' ', '\r', '\n', '?', '!', ';', '.', ',', '`', ':', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '|', '\'', '\\', '~', '=', '@', '>', '<', '&', '%', '-', '/', '#' };
```

Comment: No regular expression is needed for this.

Comment: can u be a little descriptive to solve my scenario?

Comment: Do you want to remove all occurences of any of these characters from a given string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the regex you want:

```
var re = /[ \r\n?!;.,`:(){}\[\]\|\'\\~=@><&%-\/#]/g;
```

For example:

```
var test = "j a\nv\ra?s!c;r.i,p`t:I(s)A{w}e[s]o|m'e\\~=@><&%-/#";
test.replace(re, '')

>>> "javascriptIsAwesome"
```

FYI, the general notation for this sort of thing in regular expressions is "/[...]/" - means, "match any character inside the brackets"

Answer (score 2):

```
var in = "...";
var out = in.replace(/[ \r\n?!:;\-(){}\[\]\\'"=@><&%\/#]+/g, '');
```

I may have missed a couple of characters.

An alternative solution may be to take a white list rather than black list approach:

```
var out = in.replace(/[^\w]+/g, '');
```

This will remove anything that *isn't* a word character, meaning a letter (uppercase or lowercase), digit or underscore.

Comment: This is not working. I tried , it can't give the replaced string. anyways thanks for the effort

Comment: I want to replace only those characters (strictly) mentioned in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var delimiters = [' ', '\r', '\n', '?', '!', ';', '.', ',', '`', ':', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '|', '\'', '\\', '~', '=', '@', '>', '<', '&', '%', '-', '/', '#'],
    re = new RegExp("[" + delimiters.join("").replace(/[-\\\]]/g, "\\$&") + "]", "g");
str = str.replace(re, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would write a function that escapes any character that could have a special meaning in a regexp, applies the regexp and returns the result:

```
String.prototype.exclude = function(blacklist) {
    for(var i=0; i<blacklist.length; i++) {
        if(blacklist[i].match(/\W/)) {
            blacklist[i] = '\\'+blacklist[i];
        }
    }
    return this.replace(new RegExp('['+blacklist.join('')+']', 'g'), '');
};

var myString = "j a\nv\ra?s!c;r.i,p`t:I(s)A{w}e[s]o|m'e\\~=@><&%-/#"; 

myString.exclude([' ', '\r', '\n', '?', '!', ';', '.', ',', '`', ':', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '|', '\'', '\\', '~', '=', '@', '>', '<', '&', '%', '-', '/', '#']);

// returns "JavascriptIsAwesome" which is of course the correct answer
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be too aggressive.

```
/[^A-z0-9]/g
```

Comment: I want to replace only those characters (strictly) mentioned in the list.

Comment: OK, in which case don't use the above.